# How to enable and disable cells in uitableview

Tags: iphone

I have a project in which I want to disable the cells of a `UITableView` at the beginning when the view loads, and after pressing a button, the cells of the `UITableView` should be enabled and should work properly.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please clear up what you mean by they should look enabled and disabled?

Answer (score 8):

You can use 
    table.allowsSelection = NO;
in your viewwillappear method and then make it YES onbutton click event.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make entire table disable then u can use:

```
table.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;
```

And then on click on the button:

```
table.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//In UIButton pressed event
 boolEnabled=YES; //Declare it in header file
[yourTableView reloadData]; //reload UITableView

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

      //After creating a cell

      if(boolEnabled==YES) //Will enable for any action
      {
            cell.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
      }
      else
      { //disable for any action
        cell.userInteractionEnabled=NO; //Default boolEnabled=NO;
      }     
 }
```

Comment: There's one other property `cell.enable` that you can also set to `YES` or `NO`.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is have a `@property (nonatomic) BOOL tableIsActive`

In my `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` I would do

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(self.tableIsActive)
    {
         //style cells for enabled table
    }
    else
    {
         //style cells for enabled table
    }
}
```

And then in my `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` I would

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(self.tableIsActive)
    {
         //handle selection
    }
    else
    {
         [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    }
}
```

And then I would have a function `-(void) enableTable:(id)sender` which I bind to my button that does

```
-(void) enableTable:(id)sender
{
    if(self.tableIsActive)
        self.tableIsActive = NO;
    else
        self.tableIsActive = YES;
}
```

And then after enabling call `[yourTable reloadData];`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the below code , Just check for the condition in TableView delgate method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *categoryIdentifier = @"Category";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    //Way to stop to choose the cell selection
     if(indexpath.row==0)
        {
         cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
         Or 
         cell.userIneractionEnabled=False;
        }
       //while rest of the cells will remain active, i.e Touchable

    return cell;

}
```