# How to enable and disable cells in uitableviews

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HOw to enable and disable cells in uitableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974485/how-to-enable-and-disable-cells-in-uitableview)

I want to disable cell selection initially and then after pressing button ...

I want to make it enable after pressing of button