# How enabling and disabling tableview cell selection on button click

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HOw to enable and disable cells in uitableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974485/how-to-enable-and-disable-cells-in-uitableview)

I want to disable cell selection initially and then after pressing button ...

I want to make it enable after pressing of button..

Even when the table view cells are disabled it should look like they are disabled and when are enabled ,should look like enabled....

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974911/how-to-enable-and-disable-cells-in-uitableviews

And this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974485/how-to-enable-and-disable-cells-in-uitableview