# How to disable and enable cells selection in uitableview on button click

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HOw to enable and disable cells in uitableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974485/how-to-enable-and-disable-cells-in-uitableview)

I am new to iphone..
I made a project in which initially the cells of the tableview will be disabled and after clicking some button ..the cells selection gets enabled..

The disabling of the cell should be like.people can see that now it is disabled for selection and after button click..again the user can see that the cel selection is enabled...

How can it be

Comment: It is about selecting or deselecting only particular cell or entire table completely.

Answer (score 2):

For disabling selection use:

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

and for enabling selection use:

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault];
```

Comment: not working ...

Answer (score 1):

To disable Selection of cell
     cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
To make user feel that cell are disabled
     cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    return cell;
}
```

using any condition you can disable enable pericular cell .

Answer (score 0):

In the action of button click get the instance of `cell` and set its `user interaction` false or true as you want like this -

```
UITableViewCell *cellView = (UITableViewCell*)[tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0]];

[cellView setUserInteractionEnabled:FALSE];
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer..

To show it as disabled cell...

cell.label.alpha=0.43f   (constant value)
and set table interaction=NO;

and for making it enabled

cell.label.alpha=1.0f
and set table interaction=yes;